# Interacción entre 2 function PHP se ejecuta de forma incompleta

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, function

Chicos me ocupa lo siguiente:
Tengo el las siguientes funciones PHP:

```
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['procesar_rechazo_de_pagos_btn'])) {
        procesar_rechazo_de_pagos();
    } 
    function rechazar_pagos(){
          global $db, $logo, $footer_correo;

          $id         = ($_REQUEST['id']); // Id del Pedido o Mensualidad
          $rowUser    = ($_REQUEST['user']); // Numero de Usuario
          $a          = ($_REQUEST['asunto']); // Determinar el Asunto

// Con el siguiente if determino que hacer si el asunto es un PEDIDO o una MENSUALIDAD
          if ($a == 'pedido') {

//Si es PEDIDO ejecuta el siguiente query de seleccion de la tabla PEDIDOS

            $query = "SELECT pedidos.*, users.nombre, users.email, users.username FROM pedidos INNER JOIN users  ON pedidos.usuario=users.idusuario WHERE pedidos.id = '$id' ";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query) or mysqli_error($db);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
             {

                $monto          = $row['monto'];
                $banco_emisor   = $row['banco_emisor'];
                $banco_destino  = $row['banco_destino'];
                $nro_transf     = $row['nro_transf'];
                $ci_nro_cuenta  = $row['ci_nro_cuenta'];
                $fecha_transf   = $row['fecha_transf'];
                $nombre         = $row['nombre'];

            $date = date_create($fecha_transf);
            $fecha = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');
            $fecha_pedido = $fecha;

// Con los datos obtenidos del query saco un resumen de los datos en la variable $resumen

            $resumen = 'Por un Monto de: '.$monto . ' BsS <br> Desde el Banco: '.
            $banco_emisor . ' <br> A nuestra Cuenta del: '.
            $banco_destino . ' <br> Numero de Transferencia: '.
            $nro_transf . '<br> Numero de Cedula del titular de la cuenta origen: '.
            $ci_nro_cuenta . '<br> Efectuado en fecha: '.
            $fecha_pedido . '<br> ';

            }

          } 
//En cambio si el asunto es MENSUALIDAD se ejecuta otro query y lo separo con un else if

else if ($a == 'mensualidad') {
            $query = "SELECT pagos.*, users.nombre, users.email, users.username FROM pagos INNER JOIN users  ON pagos.user=users.idusuario WHERE pagos.id = '$id' ";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query) or mysqli_error($db);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
             {

                $monto          = $row['monto'];
                $banco_emisor   = $row['banco_origen'];
                $banco_destino  = $row['banco_destino'];
                $nro_transf     = $row['nro_transf'];
                $ci_nro_cuenta  = $row['ci_nro_cuenta'];
                $fecha_transf   = $row['fecha_transf'];
                $plan           = $row['afiliacion'];
                $concepto       = $row['concepto'];
                $nombre         = $row['nombre'];

            $date = date_create($fecha_transf);
            $fecha = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');
            $fecha_de_transf = $fecha;

//Aca nuevamente la variable $resumen si el asunto es MENSUALIDAD

            $resumen = 'Por un Monto de: '.$monto . ' BsS <br>
            Desde el Banco: '. $banco_emisor . ' <br>
            A nuestra Cuenta del: '. $banco_destino . ' <br>
            Numero de Transferencia: '. $nro_transf . '<br>
            Numero de Cedula del titular de la cuenta origen: '. $ci_nro_cuenta . '<br>
            Efectuado en fecha: '. $fecha_de_transf . '<br> ';

          }


          }

// aca declaro la variable salida que se mostrara en la web

          $salida = '<b>'. strtoupper($a).'</b><br>'.strtoupper($a) .' Identificador '. $id . '<br> Del Usuario: '. $nombre . '<br> Identificador: '. $rowUser . '<br>'. $resumen;

// aca declaro la variable salida con el id codificado que es lo que se enviara al correo electronico del usuario

          $salida_codificada = '<b>'. strtoupper($a).'</b><br>'.strtoupper($a) .' Identificador '. base64_encode($id) . '<br> Del Usuario: '. $nombre . '<br> Identificador: '. $rowUser . '<br>'. $resumen;
          // base64_decode PARA DECODIFICAR

// La variable $editar_contenido contendra el formulario que se enviara a la function procesar_rechazo_de_pagos()

          $editar_contenido = ' <form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "rechazar.php?id='.$id.'&user='.$rowUser.'&asunto='.$a.'&contenido='.$salida_codificada.'&nro_transf='. $nro_transf .'">';

          $editar_contenido .= '<label for="motivo">Motivo del Rechazo</label>
        <textarea width = "100%" type="text" class="form-control" id="motivo" aria-describedby="motivo" placeholder="Ingrese el motivo" name="motivo" ></textarea>
        ';
        $editar_contenido .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="procesar_rechazo_de_pagos_btn">Rechazar</button></form>';

        // Aca se imprime lo que va en la web.

            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
            echo $salida;
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 form-group">';
            echo $editar_contenido;
            echo '</div>';

            echo '</div>';



        }
```

Esta otra Function ejecuta los datos que se recopilan de la function anterior.

```
     function procesar_rechazo_de_pagos(){
            global $db, $fecha_act, $logo, $footer_correo;

            $status = "RECHAZADO";

           $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
           $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
           $a = $_REQUEST['asunto'];
           $contenido = $_REQUEST['contenido'];
           $motivo = $_REQUEST['motivo'];
           $nro_transf  = $status .' ' . $_REQUEST['nro_transf'] . ' ' . $status;
        // En el siguiente query tomo los datos de la base de datos correspondiente al usuario

           $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'";
           $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or mysqli_error($db); 
           $c = $db->query($sql);
           while($row_user = $c->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
           {
               $nombre = $row_user['nombre'];
               $email = $row_user['email'];
           }

//Aca segun el el valor de la variable $a que es el asunto (puede ser PEDIDO o MENSUALIDAD se ejecutaran los UPDATE en la base de datos correspondiente

        if ($a == 'pedido'){

            $query = "UPDATE pedidos SET
            status_pedido = '$status',
            motivo_rechazo = '$motivo',
            fecha_rechazo = '$fecha_act',
            nro_transf = '$nro_transf'
            WHERE id = '$id'";
            if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
                $_SESSION['rechazar']  = "Se ha Actualizado el STATUS del Pedido a RECHAZADO..!!<br>";
                } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
                //mysqli_close($db);
                }
        } else if ($a == 'mensualidad'){

            $query = "UPDATE pagos SET
            status_pago = '$status',
            motivo_rechazo = '$motivo',
            fecha_rechazo = '$fecha_act',
            nro_transf = '$nro_transf'
            WHERE id = '$id'";
            if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
                $_SESSION['rechazar']  = "Se ha Actualizado el STATUS del pago de Mensualidad a RECHAZADO..!!<br>";
                } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
                //mysqli_close($db);
                }
                }
        // Aca se envia un correo de la actualizacion hecha en la Base de Datos

        $email = $email;
        $nombre = $nombre;
        $asunto = "Se ha Rechazado su Pago";
        $cuerpo = "Cuerpo del email";
        enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo);

         $_SESSION['rechazar']  .= '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Se ha enviado un correo electronico notificando sobre este rechazo de pago..!!<br>';     

        }
```

Los datos de origen de la **function rechazar_pagos()** se obtienen desde un botón que pasa los datos necesarios (ESTO ESTA FUNCIONANDO), y resulta que en si la variable `$a = ($_REQUEST['asunto']);` es igual a **pedido** toda la function de rechazo se ejecuta de manera perfecta hasta el envío del correo, pero cuando la variable `$a = ($_REQUEST['asunto']);` es igual a **mensualidad** el  botón **Rechazar** no funciona, como que si estuviera desactivado, el PHP no me da reporte de error, dejo esto por aquí a ver si algún colega puede visualizar el error que estoy cometiendo y me ayuda a identificarlo.

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara y la organización del código no es que ayude mucho. Tienes dos `if ($a == 'pedido'){`, uno en el `SELECT` y otro en el `UPDATE` ¿a cuál de los dos te refieres cuando dices que no funciona? ¿Por ejemplo en el primer `if` no sacas nada por pantalla. Al leer el código tampoco se entiende muy bien lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Saludos @A.Cedano he editado mi consulta, he comentado las functions con la finalidad de que se pueda comprender lo que tengo, y es super extraño porque resulta que si el asunto fuera un **pedido** se ejecuta sin novedad, pero si el asunto es **mensualidad** el boton de rechazo no funciona..! al dar click no ejecuta nada.

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado recurriendo a lo basico
He modificado en mi codigo el formulario de envio quedandome de la siguiente manera:

```
 $editar_contenido = '<form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "rechazar.php">';

  $editar_contenido .= '
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'">
  <input type="hidden" name="user" value="'.$rowUser.'">
  <input type="hidden" name="asunto" value="'.$a.'">
  <input type="hidden" name="contenido" value="'.$salida_codificada.'">
  <input type="hidden" name="nro_transf" value="'.$nro_transf.'">';

  $editar_contenido .= '<label for="motivo">Motivo del Rechazo</label>
<textarea width = "100%" type="text" class="form-control" id="motivo" aria-describedby="motivo" placeholder="Ingrese el motivo" name="motivo" ></textarea>
';
$editar_contenido .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="procesar_rechazo_de_pagos_btn">Rechazar</button></form>';
```

He pasado los datos que necesito con el uso de INPUT ocultos y de esa manera si mis funciones operan en ambos casos, cuando el asunto es **pedido** o **mensualidad**